# sql not getting the second value

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, laravel-4

I have the below query which has been working just fine till now when i add the second where clause.

```
$query = "SELECT exam_venue AS venue FROM application WHERE level_apply = '".$levelappy."' and city_applied = '".$city."' GROUP BY venue HAVING COUNT(id) < 20 LIMIT 1";
             $class = mysql_query($query);

             if (!$class) { // add this check.
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
             }
             $row = mysql_fetch_array($class);
             $class1 = $row['venue'];
             dd($class1);
```

The above code always returns null although if i try the same query in database there are data there. I do have the data in the two variables in the query but i dont know why the query is not taking the city at all. without city it gives the result but when i add the city it returns null.

even if i try the same query without adding any variable it returns null while in database it returns the venue = '1A-1'

```
SELECT exam_venue AS venue FROM application WHERE level_apply = '1' and city_applied = 'Prishtinë' GROUP BY venue HAVING COUNT(id) < 20
```

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_` API anymore. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) prepared statements.

Comment: use this once $query = "SELECT exam_venue AS venue FROM application WHERE level_apply = $levelappy and city_applied = $city GROUP BY venue HAVING COUNT(id) < 20";

Comment: I use LIMIT 1 because i just want the first row

Comment: @bassxzero I tried without LIMIT 1 but still the same result

Comment: @MuharremSmakiqi Sorry didn't read it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$levelappy` variable spelled correct? I can see the column name in your query is level_apply, are you missing an L?

Also, it may help to use:

```
$query = "SELECT exam_venue AS venue 
FROM application 
WHERE level_apply = '{$levelapply}' 
AND city_applied = '{$city}' 
GROUP BY venue HAVING COUNT(id) < 20
LIMIT 1"
```

As then you don't have to concatenate the string.

Comment: Not working, and yes the $levelappy is correct because i get an input from view in that

Comment: the query is working the problem was that in my database the city_applied is with capital letter ex. London. If l change from London to london it will work.
How can i solve this issue with sql?

Comment: You can try using the LOWER() function in the WHERE statement. So AND LOWER(city_applied) = '{$city}' Let me know how it goes.